# Toggle div's with the same classes but individually, not all at once?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've got the following HTML and because I'm using Wordpress, I cannot change the class for each div.

```
<div class="show_hide">content1</div>
<div class="extended">extension of content 1</div>
<div class="show_hide">content2</div>
<div class="extended">extension of content 2</div>
```

My jQuery script is as follows:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function(){


        $(".sliding").hide(0);
        $(".show_hide").show(0);

    $('.show_hide').click(function(){
    $(".sliding").slideToggle(0);
    });

});

</script>
```

Now, when clicking on the show_hide div, both div's with class "extended" show. I would like to show only the extension the div clicked on. Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If the `.extended` element is the immediately following sibling of the `.show_hide` element, you can use [`next`](http://api.jquery.com/next/):

```
$('.show_hide').click(function(){
    $(this).next().slideToggle(0);
});
```

If there are other elements in between, you can use [`nextAll`](http://api.jquery.com/nextAll/), and then reduce the selection to the first match (with [`eq`](http://api.jquery.com/eq/)):

```
$('.show_hide').click(function(){
    $(this).nextAll('.extended').eq(0).slideToggle(0);
});
```

Answer (score 3):

In callback functions, the variable `this` will contain a reference to the DOM node that triggered the event:

```
$(this).next().slideToggle(0);
```